# Issues configuring AWS Route 53 for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am attempting to use a domain registered with Amazon Route 53 to access an Elastic Beanstalk (nodejs) site. I originally had it working ok, but something broke and I can't for the life of me get it to work again.

In summary, I have:

1. An Elastic Beanstalk environment that is accessible via its url (i.e. ***.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com)
2. A domain registered through Amazon Route 53
3. A hosted zone in Route 53, with a document added with Type=A and routing traffic to the Alias (to my Elastic beanstalk environment)
4. I have edited the named servers in the registered domain to match that of the hosted zone

When I do a "Test Record" from the Hosted Zone, it returns "DNS response code No Error", and returns the IP address of my Elastic Beanstalk application. But, when i go to the URL I get "The Requested Host you requested is not resolvable."

As mentioned, I originally had it working. I then attempted to set up a redirect from http to https via Cloud Front, and managed to break it. I have subsequently removed all https & cloud front config in attempt to get the basic URL access working again. I suspect my issue is that I deleted my default Hosted Zone created by Amazon when I registered the domain, and I have a setting wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your hosted zone's A record pointing to the correct Elastic Beanstalk environment? It's also possible to point it to your load balancer when using HTTP to HTTPS. Did you do this at all?

Comment: Yes it is the correct Elastic Beanstalk environment. I only have one. And like I say, when I do a Test Record, it returns the IP address of that environment.
I tried what you suggested with the Load Balancer as well but still no luck.

Comment: Are you sure your hosted zone is public & not private?

Comment: Yes definitely public

Comment: I'm thinking I might set up a whole new elastic beanstalk environment and repoint everything to that. See if that can reset something. Watch this space

Comment: @MrNooNoo I'm not sure if you have the issue resolved? I had it recently and I haven't figured out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I never got to the bottom of this. Instead created a new elastic beanstalk environment, then reconfigured the domain and certificate to the new instance.
I have no idea what the difference is as all settings appear to be the same. But it at least gave me a way forward.